# Excel - how to skip columns when creating a Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot

All,

I have an Excel sheet with first a few basic basic input data (example below: column a, b), than a lot of more technical intermediate calculations (columns c, d) and than the business results (columns e, f).

It is possible to create a Pivot table using only columns a, b, e and f, not showing c and d?

Source data:

[image: Source data]

Pivot I have today:

[image: pivot 1]

Pivot I would like to have:

[image: pivot 2]

Reason why this is important to me: in the real sheet there are a lot of intermediate calculations. This is very confusing for the users of my Excel sheet. Moreover the users double click values in the pivots to find the details, but these details show many columns they do not understand.

Thank you!

Comment: can't you just hide these columns before distribution?

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I hide columns C and D and when I create a pivot on A:F, the hidden columns still show up in the pivot. When I double click on a value in the pivot, the hidden columns will also be shown.

Comment: And I can also not delete the columns. The sheet is dynamic. The user can input some values in another sheet, which will trigger calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, if you have a version of Excel that includes the PowerPivot add-in, such as Excel 365/2016 version with the Professional Plus SKU. If you've got such a version, then first you need to enable the PowerPivot addin, and then when you create a PivotTable from the source table, be sure to check the "Add this data to the Data Model" option as shown below:

[image]

Then after you have created the PivotTable, choose Manage from the PowerPivot tab:

[image]

...and click on the Diagram View icon in the ribbon, then click and then right-click on the fields of interest and select the "Hide from Client Tools" option:

[image]

...and then the user can't see those fields back in Excel:

[image]

Google PowerPivot to find out more.

Comment: Thank you for your solution!